# How can I make my slick slider work like it should be?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm looking to use slick for my slider but for some reasons it won't work and I don't really know why. Everything seems fine but there's obviously a mistake which I hope someone can help me with.

```html
<div class="cate_slider">
    <div>
        <p>Écologiste</p>
        <?= $this->Html->image('euros2.png', ['alt' => 'Image Écologiste', 'class' => 'cate_mini'])?>
        <p><span class="keyword">Pour retrouver la sérénité...</span><br>Détendez-vous, respirez pleinement aide à prendre conscience des éléments utiles qui vous entours. Laissez place au vide apaisera votre esprit.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Écologiste</p>
        <?= $this->Html->image('euros2.png', ['alt' => 'Image Écologiste', 'class' => 'cate_mini'])?>
        <p><span class="keyword">Pour retrouver la sérénité...</span><br>Détendez-vous, respirez pleinement aide à prendre conscience des éléments utiles qui vous entours. Laissez place au vide apaisera votre esprit.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Écologiste</p>
        <?= $this->Html->image('euros2.png', ['alt' => 'Image Écologiste', 'class' => 'cate_mini'])?>
        <p><span class="keyword">Pour retrouver la sérénité...</span><br>Détendez-vous, respirez pleinement aide à prendre conscience des éléments utiles qui vous entours. Laissez place au vide apaisera votre esprit.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Écologiste</p>
        <?= $this->Html->image('euros2.png', ['alt' => 'Image Écologiste', 'class' => 'cate_mini'])?>
        <p><span class="keyword">Pour retrouver la sérénité...</span><br>Détendez-vous, respirez pleinement aide à prendre conscience des éléments utiles qui vous entours. Laissez place au vide apaisera votre esprit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.center').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '60px',
        slidesToShow: 3,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '40px',
                    slidesToShow: 3
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '40px',
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide more information and proper code it seems you didn't pasted all the code.

Comment: errors in console?

Comment: by the way, `$('.center').slick` but there is no element with class "center", maybe it's supposed to be `$('.cate_slider').slick`

Comment: Yep my bad on this it's settled with the right class. I don't have any errors in my console.
Any of my slides are being displayed and I can't figure out why. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out where my problem was.

I add the slick css file not being loaded (how silly of me) it's now working.

Thx for the thoughts guys <3